# Run bash command in CocoaPods post_install step

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I would like to make CocoaPods run `git submodule init` in the project root directory after it's done installing the pods. There is a post_install hook, but I found very little information about how to use it. Can it be used to run arbitrary bash commands?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Well, that was easier than expected...

```
post_install do |installer|
  system("git submodule init")
end
```

Comment: you can also run sh scripts using the same command. e.g. system(sh mysh.sh). Thanks for the answer.